# Android game crashed after displaying unity's splash screen

Tags: android, logcat, splash-screen, unity-game-engine

I found this question on different forums but they didn't helped me to find solution of my issue. I had port unity(**5.4**) game on my android device (OS **4.4**). When i opened the game it crashed after displaying unity's default splash screen. **I wonder, it was working fine on unity's editor but didn't worked well on device.**

Here is the logcat file [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/imAliAsad/issues/master/logcat.txt). Please let me know if i can provide any additional information that may help to track the issue. Many thanks.

Regards,
Ali

Comment: Link is broken. Why not you upload the log to pastebin?

Comment: sorry for that. It is fix now. please click again @Jeremy :-)

Comment: Code please ???

Comment: Which code you would like to read. because project contain tons of code files. Please let me know I'll share the code with you. Thanks @UnknownDeveloper

Comment: I don't understand why community giving this question - negative points??

Comment: Is your AndroidManifest ok?

Comment: yeah it is okay. did you find anything from logcat file that i mentioned?

Comment: @AliAsad, you need to be more specific in order for the community to be able to help you. The logcat file you attached is really long, so I need you to give me more information. Had you tested your app before and now it stopped working? If so, what did you change that could have made your app crash?

Comment: @blastervla, I figured out it was texture size which causing the problem. So, I compressed it and used check Open GLES3. Thanks for addressing my issue. For logcat i do not know how much content i must share, so i shared the entire file. I apologies if it is inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

90% it's native plugins. Try to remove all your native android plugins. You can find them under Plugins/Android folder. You also need to remove all links or scripts that uses those plugins. Don't forget to make a back up. If your app won't crash, replace them with some others or connect with plugin development support.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I followed following steps.

### Solution

1. Go to 'Player Settings' -> 'Other Settings'. **Uncheck** Auto
   Graphic Api. **Remove** 'OpenGLES2' from list.
2. Test your game on better android device. In my case i tested on Samsung Glaxy S5.

[image]

---

### If solution doesn't work

1. Remove all objects from scene. Port the project and test, if that
   works, it means you need to remove unnecessary objects from scene
   that need a lot of render power to load on mobile device.
2. Make sure your Android SDK is uptodated a long with JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure Virtual Reality support is unchecked